# Cannot use property paths with rdflib

Tags: sparql, rdflib

I am trying to use property paths with rdflib 4.2.1.
With the following class hierarchy:

```
Clothing
 Women
  TopsWomen
   TShirtWomen
```

an instance (:aShirt) of type TShirtWomen, and the following query

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?type where {
   :aShirt a/(rdfs:subClassOf)* ?type .
 }
```

I would expect to see all parent classes, but only receive TShirtWomen.

Comment: The query is correct. Are you sure that the data is correct, i.e. no typos etc? And all the data is loaded into the same graph?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use SPARQL, i.e. like in the example here: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/examples/foafpaths.py

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the instance type declaration was made as a Literal and not URIRef.